# Internal USB headers inside a nuc

Tags: intel-nuc

I've been searching the internet but can't seem to find an answer. I have a piece of software that requires a license dongle to be inserted at all times (in case it matters it's the ETC Nomad software for lighting control).

I was wondering if it was possible to put the dongle inside the NUC and somehow connect it to the internal USB headers (maybe with a tiny short cable I can coil up inside).

My purpose is two fold: one, to prevent causal theft (the NUC itself will be locked down with a lock cable), and to not take up any USB 3.0 ports on the outside of the device to leave room for other things.

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly possible if there's enough space inside for the dongle. The Intel NUC has headers for 3 internal USB 2.0 ports, so that's sufficient.

EDIT: As mentioned in the comments, there are ready-made adapters available, flexible (e.g. [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000IV6S9)) or fixed (e.g. [here](http://www.lindy-usa.com/usb-20-motherboard-header-adapter-33459.html)).

Comment: There are adapters available, both [flexible](https://www.amazon.com/StarTech-Motherboard-4-Pin-Header-USBMBADAPT/dp/B000IV6S9S) and [fixed](http://www.lindy-usa.com/usb-20-motherboard-header-adapter-33459.html).

Comment: @DanielB: Ah, nice.